# Is it correct to create a reference variable of a class inside the same class ? How is it different from a normal object creation using new keyword?

Tags: java, class

```
Class Test {
   Test variable1 = null;
   Test variable2 = new Test();
}
```

Can we perform similar functions with both variables ?

Comment: When would you stop defining Test objects though?

Comment: `variable2` will cause StackOverflowException since *while creating* each Test instance would require its own Test instance, which would require its own Test instance, and so on.

Comment: To be clear, it is OK to have reference variable of same type as class. Because of that we can have structures like LinkedList which internally has `Node` which holds reference to another Node. What is the problem is fact that in `variable2` you are initializing it with another instance of your class. This initialization will be moved to each constructor, which will result in infinite recursion and stack overflow.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it correct to create a reference variable of a class inside the
>   same class ?

**Yes it is correct**

You will understand more with an example, Consider you have a class **Person** :

```
class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

    Person mother;
    Person father;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person(String name, int age, Person mother, Person father) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
    }

}
```

Every one is a person which have mother and father, and mother and father are Person.

For example you :

```
Person p1 = new Person("Son Name", 22, 
       new Person("Mother name"), 45), new Person("Father name"), 50));
```

Or you can create it like this :

```
Person mother = new Person("Mother name", 45);
Person father = new Person("Father name", 50);
Person son =    new Person("Son name", 22, mother, father);
```

Like you see, you can play with your constructor, like you want.

Comment: @Aganju check the example that i already mention, you will understand that this not `lead to infinite recursion` :)

Comment: @Aganju The term "reference variable" is incorrect here. You mean an instance variable. It only leads to infinite recursion if it's directly assigned with an instance that in turn leads to the creation of an object of the same class or subclass. If the objects to assign to the variables are passed in to the constructor or assigned after construction, it's not a problem.

Comment: @Aganju This is Java. There's no explicit pointers here. No "default" instance is created to assign to these instance variables, they are initialized to `null` by default.

Comment: This is a nice example. Have an upvote. In reality you would assert that the parent's age cannot be less than the child, which will also guard against circularities.

Comment: Sorry for missing that. Seems like I am not fully awake, and saw it as C++.

Answer (score 0):

If each of those members is initialized with `new Test()` you end up with *infinite recursion*. So no, that's not possible.

The recursion has to stop somewhere, e.g. with a null value.

Other than that there's nothing wrong with having an instance variable with the same type as the class itself. It's a completely normal variable.

Answer (score 0):

You would only have an infinite loop (stack overflow error) if you tried to do following:

```
Class Test {
   Test variable2 = new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your variables are instance variables, meaning they belong with an instance of `Test` if you create it. However, `variable2` would always lead to a stackoverflow error. Suppose you do `new Test()`:

> Test t1 = new Test(); -> t1.variable1 initialized to null, t1.variable2 initialized to new Test(); -> t1.variable2.variable2 initialized to new Test(); ...

It keeps endlessly recursing. So having the instance variable initialized directly is not an option. You've have to initialize it via a setter or in the constructor. This is perfectly valid. A class is allowed to have instance members of its own type. After all, there are use-cases for object-orientation where some thing can contain one or more instances of itself. A tree structure would be a typical example: each node can contain a number of child nodes which in turn may contain more child nodes.

Note that if you made these static, you would be capable of initializing instances immediately:

```
Class Test {
    static Test variable1 = null;
    static Test variable2 = new Test();
}
```

These would then be static members, belonging with the Test **class** rather than a specific Test **instance**.